# The apple-app-site-association file was found but it doesn’t follow the required format

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-app, applinks, ios-searchapi

I'm using this [API Validation Tool from Apple](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/) and I got 6 of 7 validation PASSED in a specific page but "Universal Links" test got this message:

"The apple-app-site-association file was found but it doesn’t follow the required format.
Learn how to format the apple-app-site-association file."

I saw this videos from WWDC 2015 "[Seamless linking to your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=509)" and "[Introducing Search API](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=709)" and read this [App Search Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH4-SW1).

My website have an SSL certificate (from Authority certified) and my apple-app-site-association is inside https://www.mywebsite.com/apple-app-site-association

This is an example for my apple-app-site-association file:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": “TeamId.com.MyCompany.MyAppName01”,
            "paths": [ “*” ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "TeamId.com.MyCompany.MyAppName02”,
            "paths": [ "*" ]
        }
    ]
   }
}
```

NOTE: The appName is Case Sensitive.

I don't know what is wrong with the file. Maybe is a syntax error but I can not see it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hi, did you got the solution?,i am also getting same error

Comment: Yes. My problem was with doble quote ("). If you check the file, I have two different types of double quotes so I need write the same in all file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They introduced a change in the format recently. According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) you need to reformat it to match this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc",
                "paths": [ "/wwdc/news/", "/videos/wwdc/2015/*" ]
            },
            {
                "appID": "TeamID.BundleID2",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Plus give Applebot some time it started to work for me on the next day. Oh, and I see that your quotemarks are wrong - make sure, that you have the right quotemarks. Use these only:

> "

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still got the same message. With sign and no signed file.

Comment: I've updated my answer, check tomorrow, or sth like this @Beto

Comment: Ok. I don't knew it about waiting time. Let me wait. Thank you.

Comment: After 18 hours still with no success and same message. I'm start thinking is a bug in the API Validation Tool, but I don't know.

Comment: OMG !! I can't believe it !! Thank you so much !!

Comment: BTW would you please give me a upvote for the question? :)

Comment: @Beto Let people who think it's gonna be helpful upvote it :)

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik hi, did you got the solution?,i am also getting same error

Comment: Did you try my solution @Ravindhiran?

Comment: yeah still i am getting "The apple-app-site-association file was found but it doesn’t follow the required format

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik  how to convert unsigned.json file into  "apple-app-site-association".
I have server.key , server.crt & bundle.crt file

Comment: @MaciekCzarnik Are you there?

Comment: Signing it is a different question @Ravindhiran, I think you can even find easily solution on SO or in some Search API tutorial